to_numeric() adds a decimal to all numeric values
I have a dataset that looks like this:
profession     Australia_F   Australia_M      Canada_F      Canada_M    Kenya_F   Kenya_M
Author         #DIV/0!       80               55            34          60        23
Librarian      10            34               89            33          89        12
Pilot          78            12               67            90          12        55

To create a heatmap out of this data, I melt it and convert values to numeric values.
melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Profession', var_name='Country_Gender', value_name='Number')


melted_df[['Country', 'Gender']] = melted_df['Country_Gender'].str.split('_', expand=True)
melted_df['Number'] = pd.to_numeric(melted_df['Number'], errors='coerce')


Before the pd.to_numeric step, the numbers are fine. However, after applying this function, two things happen:

A decimal (.0) is added to all numeric values. For example 80 becomes 80.0
#DIV/0! is changed to NULL

I am okay with changing the unkown value to NULL but I want to avoid the decimals. What can I do here?
What I need to do after this step:
heatmap_data = melted_df.pivot_table(index='Profession', columns=['Country', 'Gender'], values='Percentage')
...generating heatmap...


If you're on pandas>=2, try passing dtype_backend: pd.to_numeric(melted_df['Number'], errors='coerce', dtype_backend='numpy_nullable')

This removes the decimals but it changes the NULL to <NA>, which is not suitable for creating a heat map later. If I manually convert the <NA> like this, melted_df['Percentage'] = melted_df['Percentage'].replace('<NA>', pd.NA).astype(float), it would give me the decimals again @cottontail

<NA> is pd.NA; it's just how it's rendered. If you're using seaborn for the heatmap, I believe sns.heatmap(df.astype('float')) would draw the heatmap for nullable integer columns.

You shouldn't need to worry about the type, keep it as float and define the format in the heatmap: sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, annot=True, fmt='.0f') (although sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, annot=True) should also work).

It's because you have Nan value in your numeric data, even if you use  downcast="integer" it will be the same since Integer ("Int8") cannot keep Nan value. To convert to int you should either convert the Nan value to a custom number like "-1" and then convert to int or convert to "Int64" which is Integer that can keep Nan:
melted_df['Number'] = pd.to_numeric(melted_df['Number'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')

If you also want to have heatmap_data in integer, you must do the same:
heatmap_data = melted_df.pivot_table(index='Profession', columns=['Country', 'Gender'], values='Number')
heatmap_data = heatmap_data.astype('Int64')

